# How Do I Enable Bash Programmable Completion for Command Line Switches?

Tags: bash, shell, autocomplete

On one of my systems, bash programmable completion works for basic commands like this:

```
$ ls -l t/
01_createTicket/               02_methods.t
[etc...]
```

However, it does not work for the switches in my custom commands:

```
$ ./test_all.pl --environment=test --verbosity=1 --test=t/
[will not autocomplete; does not show contents of directory]
```

On all my other systems, the second example works.

What exactly do I need to adjust on my system to enable bash completion on the end of a long command like that?

Comment: What is the difference between the "one" and the "all other" systems?  Look for differences in bash version, `.bashrc` contents, and `set` options first.  **Also** run `complete -p` on each machine and compare to see what the differences are.

Comment: $: bash --version, GNU bash, version 4.2.46(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) on all systems.  My non-working system has a bunch of output for complete -p, my working systems do not give any output for that command.

Comment: Try running `complete -r` on your non-working system to make it match the working ones (per [this](https://blog.onetechnical.com/2012/06/19/disable-bash-autocompletion-on-ubunt/))

Comment: That worked, many thanks @cxw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your non-working system has autocompletion entries your working systems don't, as you saw in the `complete -p` output, run `complete -r` on the non-working system to clear out the completion entries ([source](https://blog.onetechnical.com/2012/06/19/disable-bash-autocompletion-on-ubunt/)).

**Edit** Completions may be loaded in any of the startup files: `/etc/profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, or `~/.profile`.  They are tested in that order ([bash(1), section "Invocation"](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)).  I suspect your `/etc/profile` is loading the completions, which is why you need `complete -r` in your `.bash_profile` to clear them out.

Comment: This does work, but one thing to note.... running `complete -r` only removes the autocompletion entries (thereby making it work better don't ask me why) for the current shell, so I placed the `complete -r` in my `.bash_profile`.  Curious if anyone knows a permanent fix for this without the `.bash_profile` entry.

Comment: @Marcus Thanks!  Edited.